# How do I cause a watchdog reset of my embedded Linux device

Tags: linux, bash, kernel, embedded, watchdog

Is there a command like

```
vi > out
vi | out
```

That I could use to cause a watchdog reset of my embedded linux device?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a watchdog on your system and a driver that uses `/dev/watchdog`, all you have to do is kill the process that is feeding it; if there is no such process, then you can `touch /dev/watchdog` once to turn it on, and if you don't touch it again, it will reset.

You also might be interested in resetting the device using the "magic sysrq" way. If you have a kernel with the `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ` feature compiled in, then you can `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` to enable it, then `echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger` to reboot. When you do this, it reboots immediately, without unmounting or or syncing filesystems.

Comment: Simply killing the watchdog daemon might not be good enough. Depending on how the watchdog device is configured it might disable the watchdog if /dev/watchdog is closed. In that case you can try sending SIGSTOP to your watchdog process instead.

Comment: If killing the watchdog daemon you must use SIGKILL and not the usual SIGTERM which performs an orderly shut-down and so closes the driver. Using SIGSTOP as suggested by @KristofProvost achieves the same goal of preventing the periodic refresh.

Comment: `SIGSTOP` will be better than `SIGKILL` when the driver stops the watchdog when the file descriptor gets closed. See [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt), especially regarding "Magic Close" and `CONFIG_WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT`.

Answer (score 9):

If you think the watchdog is running OK, and want to test that it really is capable of recovering a crashed system, then you can do one better than Shawn's answer by using the "magic sysrq" to crash the system with a kernel panic. Syncing your file system first is a good idea, so do something like this as root:

```
sync; sleep 2; sync; echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

That should cause a kernel panic if the sysrq is enabled. Then if you wait around 60 seconds (typical time-out for the watchdog module) you should see the machine reboot. Please note this will only work with hardware watchdogs and not the 'softdog' module.

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to test the watchdog. The kernel will itself reboot after 60 seconds, without any help from any watchdog, with a kernel crash like this: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a335366bad1364a07f49df9da1fdfa6d411a5f39/kernel/panic.c#L358-L367

Answer (score 1):

Killing the watchdog process is one way, but note that this is not foolproof: the behavior depends on the specific watchdog driver, see [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt), especially regarding "Magic Close" and `CONFIG_WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT`. The `sysrq` answers may also give you a false positive depending on the kernel configuration (`CONFIG_PANIC_TIMEOUT`).

I think the most straight-forward approach is to write your own, simple and intentionally-broken watchdog. The following program (based on the sample included with the kernel) worked for me:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/watchdog.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("/dev/watchdog", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("watchdog");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int timeout;
    ioctl(fd, WDIOC_GETTIMEOUT, &timeout);
    printf("The timeout was %d seconds\n", timeout);
    timeout = 1;
    ioctl(fd, WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT, &timeout);
    printf("The timeout is now %d seconds. The system should reset soon...\n", timeout);
    while (1) {
        printf("Still here...\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Run it like e.g. `gcc prog.c && sudo sync && sudo ./a.out`.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting it in one line from previous two posts:

`echo 1 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq; sync; sleep 2; sync; echo c | sudo tee -a /proc/sysrq-trigger`

Comment: downvoters dare to explain why? : )

Comment: too complicated compared to the other answers ;) ( I did not downvote )

Comment: Just because you can put multiple commands in a single line does not automatically mean that you should. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/544428/100397

Comment: @roaima I agree with your comment in general, but I think this is exactly one of those situations that I would use a one-liner.

Comment: Sure, no worries